# Wordpress - Compare date - October is bigger than November (Y-m-d)

Tags: php, wordpress, date, if-statement

I'm developing an event booking, everything works correctly with this query, that is, it puts the posts according to the order of magnitude correctly

```
<?php
$v_args = array(
    'post_type' => get_option('customer_postquery'),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array (
            'key'       => 'metakey_AMC_data',
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $queried_object,
        )
    )

);
$vehicleSearchQuery = new WP_Query( $v_args );


if( $vehicleSearchQuery->have_posts() ) :?>

    <?php while( $vehicleSearchQuery->have_posts() ) : $vehicleSearchQuery->the_post();
        ?>
        <?php
        $var = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'metakey_AMC_data',true);
        $data_dell_evento = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( $var ));
        /*PRENDERE LA DATA CORRENTE IN FORMATO Y-m-d DIRETTAMENTE DA MYSQL*/
        $data_di_oggi = date( 'Y-m-d', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );
        if ($data_dell_evento > $data_di_oggi   ): ?>

            <div style="padding-top: 25px;" class="col-md-4"><!-- Card -->
                <?php include('content/home_page/card.php');  ?>
            </div>

        <?php  endif; ?>

    <?php
    endwhile;
else :
    ?>

<?php
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

where: `get_option('customer_postquery'),` recovers all the custom post types created

where: `metakey_AMC_data`, is the meta key where the event date is enclosed in the respective meta_value

where: `$queried_object,` it retrieves the taxonomy based on the taxonomy page we are in

The problem is that it perfectly filters all the dates of October, example

- 2019/10/05
- 2019/10/10
- 2019/10/15

but when I insert a date for the following month, for example (2019/11/01), November gives me a little bit smaller than everyone, changing the arrangement in this way

- 2019/11/01
- 2019/10/05
- 2019/10/10
- 2019/10/15

how to fix this?

**more information:**

when instead I am on the event page, so I entered the page where I have all the information, this query is the one that regulates all future events only of that custom post type without distinction of taxonomies, in this case not putting get_option and not putting no taxonomy, the dates are displayed perfectly

```
$v_args = array(
    'post_type' => array('eventi-suite'),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array (
            'key'       => 'metakey_AMC_data',

        ),
    ),


);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` without passing a `meta_key`.

Quote from the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters):

> meta_value‘ – Note that a ‘meta_key=keyname‘ must also be present in the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect). Use ‘meta_value_num‘ instead for numeric values. You may also specify ‘meta_type‘ if you want to cast the meta value as a specific type. Possible values are ‘NUMERIC’, ‘BINARY’, ‘CHAR’, ‘DATE’, ‘DATETIME’, ‘DECIMAL’,

Therefore, you should change your args to something like this:

```
$v_args = array(
    'post_type' => get_option('customer_postquery'),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'metakey_AMC_data',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $queried_object,
        )
    )
);
```

Basically I changed the `meta_query` to simply use `meta_key` in the args.

### Update

The reason why it's not working in your case is because your dates are stored as `d-m-Y` format in your database, therefore, it is ordering by the day instead of the usual `year, month, day`.

Simply update the format you are saving the dates in your database.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted it into mine, but it's all the same, why?

Comment: @der Are you sure that is the right meta key? Also how are the values stored in your database?

Comment: certainly the meta key is correct, they are saved through a form inside a metabox that I created as a plugin, in format (d-m-Y) that's why I then converted the code

Comment: @der Then that is the problem exactly. Because in your database, `01` is smaller than the other dates. So the ordering is based on the day first. You can try adding a `'meta_type' => 'meta_value_datetime'`.

Comment: if I implement this all the dates are mixed

Comment: @dcer It's the way the data is saved. You should save the data as `Ymd` instead. That way, it will be ordered properly.

Comment: I just did a test by deleting all the posts and creating 3 with ymd format and they are perfect, I tried to do a conversion hoping that I was fine but nothing, thanks for your contribution, write me the answer so you mark it as correct